# Convert LocalDB to SQLite

Tags: sqlite, converters, localdb

I think I already know the answer, but just to be sure: is there a FREE program to convert a LocalDB database to SQLite? I found several paid programs with a trial period, but that puts in watermarks or converts only the first 50 records. Or maybe not a program, but another way to convert?

Comment: SQLite Toolbox which is free can do that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite Toolbox is exactly what I was looking for. It easily converted my MDF-file to a db-file.